# Is it possible rotate CSS header and make it responsive based on rotated dimensions rather than the hacky JS work around

Tags: javascript, css

Trying to make the following code snippet work without JavaScript.

```js
// This works, but aiming for a pure CSS solution
var shortWidget = document.getElementsByClassName('widget-header')[0];
var shortSpan = document.getElementById('shortHeader');
var widgetHeight = shortSpan.getBoundingClientRect().height;
shortWidget.style.height = widgetHeight + 20 + 'px';
```

```css
/* scss compiled to css */
@charset "UTF-8";
/* Trying to only use grid */
.list {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}

/* Widget */
.widget {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2rem 1fr;
}

.widget-header {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  height: 22rem;
  /*  The nasty, unresponsive hobbit */
  background-color: #0d998b;
  min-width: 0;
}
.widget-header > span {
  transform: rotate(-90deg);
  /* or use 90deg */
  white-space: nowrap;
  /* Keep header on one line */
}

.widget-content {
  border: 1px solid #0d998b;
  padding: 1rem;
}

/* This is just for making it look good, can be ignored */
html {
  font-size: 16px;
  /* Testing responsiveness */
  color: #fff;
  font-family: "Roboto", sans-serif;
  background-color: #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="widget">
  <div class="widget-header">
    <span id="shortHeader">short header</span>
  </div>
  <div class="widget-content">
    <p>This widget needs to be shrunk to be responsive</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="widget">
  <div class="widget-header">
    <span>a really long header that goes on forever</span>
  </div>
  <div class="widget-content">
    <p>This widget looks perfect</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

So my question is:

1. Is it possible to do this with just CSS?
2. Can it be done in an even better way using angular?
3. Does flex offer any benefit over the newer CSS grid in this case? (Been forcing myself to use css grid over flex)

This is the problem line:

```css
.widget-header {
  ...
  height: 22rem;  /*  The nasty, unresponsive hobbit */
  ...
}
```

I set a static 22rem, when I actually just want the widget to fit whatever is bigger (rotated header or content).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you use [`writing-mode`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/writing-mode) instead `rotate()` , it's easier to handle, no need to set an average height:
https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/poeaKXW

```css
/* Trying to only use grid */
.list {
  display: grid;
  grid-gap: 1rem;
  padding: 1rem;
}

/* Widget */
.widget {
  display: grid;
  grid-template-columns: 2rem 1fr;
}

.widget-header {
  display: grid;
  justify-content: center;
  align-items: center;
  background-color: #0d998b;
  min-width: 0;
}
.widget span {
    writing-mode:vertical-lr;
    white-space: nowrap;  /* Keep header on one line */
    padding:1em ;
    transform:scale(-1);
  
}

.widget-content {
  border: 1px solid #0d998b;
  padding: 1rem;
}

/* This is just for making it look good, can be ignored */
html {
   font-size: 16px;   /* Testing responsiveness */
   color: #fff;
   font-family: 'Roboto', sans-serif;
   background-color: #333;
}
```

```html
<div class="list">
  <div class="widget">
  <div class="widget-header">
    <span id="shortHeader">short header</span>
  </div>
  <div class="widget-content">
    <p>This widget needs <del>to be shrunk</del> to be responsive</p>
  </div>
</div>

<div class="widget">
  <div class="widget-header">
    <span>a really long header that goes on forever</span>
  </div>
  <div class="widget-content">
    <p>This widget looks perfect</p>
  </div>
</div>
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks @G-Cyrillus! That works perfectly. Was absolutely breaking my mind over this